# Automating user interface testing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, command-line, automated-tests

I'm trying to run interface tests with UISpec from the command line. I found this blog post from cocoa with love which seems to be exactly what i need :

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/automated-user-interface-testing-on.html

Unfortunatly when i add the run script build phase to my target , the build hangs up (i.e: never ends) and i get this error in the logs :

SBSetAccelerometerClientEventsEnabled failed: (ipc/send) invalid destination port

I have the same error when i'm running an empty view based project template and i tripple checked that my simulator was closed (even restarted the mac).

Has anybody been able to run an iPhone app from the command line ?

Thanks,
Vincent

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some automated test framework based on Ruby or Python? Maybe it works.